# Android, Parsing date from XML file

Tags: android, date

Hey guy's im doing some test and getting an XML file from server and parsing it to get information.

This part works but i seem to be getting an odd data and time from xml?

start="20230623020600 +0100" stop="20230623030000 +0100"

I have tried to convert Epoch, trim last 5 but always get exception..

what i noticed is that if i take that start 20230623030000

Split it 2023 06 23 030000 i get the date correct but time not sure?

seems like i would need to take last 6 to get the time? but i know that +0100 is offset

how can i get correct time?

Answer (score 0):

ok i think i got it.

From : 20230622204600 +0100
first i remove the offset +0100
then i Format
Convert to date

I need to convert to float
replace : for.

```
        val epochLongStart = it.start?.take(14)!!.toLong()
        val epochLongEnd = it.stop?.take(14)!!.toLong()

        val sdfn = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm") //18:03

        val formatedStart = java.util.Date(epochLongStart * 1000)
        val formatedEnd = java.util.Date(epochLongEnd * 1000)

        val nStart =sdfn.format(formatedStart)
        val nEnd =sdfn.format(formatedEnd)

        val strDateStart: String = nStart.replace(":", ".")
        val strDateEnd: String = nEnd.replace(":", ".")

        val floatValueStart = java.lang.Float.valueOf(strDateStart)
        val floatValueEnd = java.lang.Float.valueOf(strDateEnd)
```